# Go mod vendored dependencies being downloaded not ignored

Tags: go, module, dependency-management, vendor

I have multiple dependencies for an application.  Is it possible to have some dependencies vendored(application vendored code local that I can add debugging when deployed) and some that are downloaded via go.mod/sum. When I attempt to do this the dependencies vendored and in the modules.txt get pulled down regardless. Am I missing a step? Do I need to update the imports, go.mod/sum additionally to prevent this?

vendor/modules.txt

```
# github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go v2.0.0+incompatible
github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go
# github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-go v0.4.0
github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-go
```

Comment: No, you either vendor your dependencies or you don't. If you want different sources for local development, use workspaces.

Comment: If you want to modify a dependency, you should generally fork it and import the fork rather than modifying a vendored dependency, because it makes a more clear change log and makes it easier to pull in updates from the upstream.

Comment: ok thank you for the replies ill look at forking in the short term so I can debug possible issues.